# Can we schedule a Worksheet on Snowflake?

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, scheduling

I have recently started to use snowflake and trying to get my hands on this tool.
I am trying to copy a table from my Snowflake to an Azure storage Blob using the copy into statement creating an external stage.
I was wondering if there is a way to schedule a worksheet like every in 5 min or a particular time of the day daily? And if there is a way to trigger this worksheet only when there is a change in the table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot do that directly with the worksheet but you can run scheduled things via [Tasks](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is an option to schedule a worksheet, but you should be able to achieve this with a Task.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html

Answer (score 0):

Worksheet is just a web UI tool for users to run blocks of scripts independently and I do not think currently you can manage the worksheet via scripts or API in Snowflake.

As mentioned here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-worksheet.html

> Saved worksheets are not accessible outside of the Snowflake web interface.

You should use Tasks as mentioned by other folks:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

As everyone have mentioned, it is not directly possible. But, I think it should be possible with creating a Stored Procedure. Please check the below link to the documentation.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-snowflake-scripting